# yii2 and select2 for tags

Tags: mysql, widget, yii2

I'm using kartik select2 widget like this:

```
echo Select2::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'script_tags',
        'data' => $model->tagList,
        'options' => ['multiple' => true,'placeholder' => 'Select states ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'tags' => true
        ],
    ]);
```

`$model->tagList` is array in this format `['id'=>'name']` populated from database.

My question is what is the best why to save it into db table because with custom tags i have response for script_tags like this

`[0=>'1', 1=>'5', 2=>'math'],`

i need to save new tag in table `tag[fields=id, name]` and relations for all tags in table `tagmap[fields=id, script_id, tag_id]`

should i check if is integer save relations in `tagmap`, if is string save first new tag in tag table then save relation in `tagmap`

Comment: I think you have to change `Tag's table` to use name like is Primary Key, without numeric identify, and replace links with by model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks fine, except when somebody explicitly enters a number as tag value. Let's imagine in your tag table ID `1` is `'foo'` and ID `5` is `'bar'`. There's no way to tell if you got a `'foo,bar,math'` or `'foo,5,math'`. You could check if those IDs actually exist in your database and act accordingly, but that's probably overkill.

However, I suggest you take a look at some tagging solutions that already exist. I'm pretty happy with [2amigos/yii2-taggable-behavior](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-taggable-behavior), but there's also [creocoder/yii2-taggable](https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-taggable) and probably many others.

As an added benefit, 2amigos taggable also stores tag frequencies.

Keep in mind that having an `id` column in `tagmap`, which I bet is an autoincrement PK, is bad practice, you should use `(script_id, tag_id)` as a composite PK.

Comment: Thank you very much for tips. `2amigos/yii2-taggable-behavior` is actualy what i want. I think i don't need to reinvent the wheel.